# Reverse engineering XKCD 1190

Tags: javascript, websites

The latest (as of now) comic is titled ["Time"](http://xkcd.com/1190/). It's a standard-looking comic though without much action, but the picture's alt title says "Wait for it.". I waited but nothing happened (tried in Opera and IE9) so I took a look at the page source.

Next to the picture's `<img>` tag there was a `<script>` which included the following URL:

http://imgs.xkcd.com/static/time07.min.js

I tried to make sense of it, but I can't figure it out. Can someone explain how it works and what was supposed to happen?

Comment: [explainxkcd can and did](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kMIFRZ7MkWAJ:www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php%3Ftitle%3D1190:_Time+xkcd+1190+explained&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) (at least partially)

Comment: @Gilles: interesting! However, there doesn't seem to be much explanation on what exactly the script does, but more of "here's the URLs it fetches". I hope someone can post an overview of the script's main parts and how they interact. I, for one, am lost in all the callbacks and closures.

Comment: Perhaps it is a social experiment and is counting how long a person will wait for the image to change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somebody at XKCD fora pasted a link to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cincodenada/5246094) which contains a deobfuscated and annotated source along with some explanations:

> The main part of Javascript that drives xkcd's "Time" comic (http://xkcd.com/1190/), deobfuscated and annotated. The bulk of the script seems to be an implementation of EventSource - which, while important, is not terribly interesting for our purposes, so I've omitted it here. After some Googling around, I am in fact fairly certain that the EventSource implementation used here is https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource - after minifying and beautifying that code, it looks very similar to what shows up in time07.min.js.

As far as I can tell, it has no magic in it and serves just as a simple way for the server to let the client know when there is a new image.